# Reorder each pixel of a SpatRaster by size

Tags: r, terra

I have a SpatRaster with 100 layers, each corresponding to a result of a bootstrapping analysis (all slightly different variations but pretty much the same). I want to reorder each pixel so that the first layer is the smallest of each respective pixel, second layer is second smallest, etc.

It can be converted to a data.frame with 102 columns (x, y, result1, ...), but I don't know how to order each row of a data.frame by size and exclude columns at the same time.

Comment: Please always include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* when you ask an R question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` to order the values of each grid cell. Illustrated below

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=5, nrow=5)
values(r) <- 30
x <- rast(c(a=r, b=r/10, c=r/100))
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 5, 5, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 72, 36  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#sources     : memory  
#              memory  
#              memory  
#names       :  a, b,   c 
#min values  : 30, 3, 0.3 
#max values  : 30, 3, 0.3
```

Solution

```
y <- sort(x)
y
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 5, 5, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 72, 36  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#names       :   a, b,  c 
#min values  : 0.3, 3, 30 
#max values  : 0.3, 3, 30
```